# Disable caching for certian IP's using varnish

Tags: varnish

Is it possible to let clients with certain IP's pass thru to the backend and not cache using varnish? I don't see this in any of the example configs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think better way is described here https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2011-October/021278.html

if you have list of IP's you should create an acl list:

```
acl passem {
        "192.168.55.0/24";
}
```

and then in vcl.recv you should

```
  if (client.ip ~ passem) {
    return(pass);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this answer from the mailing list.

Yes, you can:

```
if (client.ip == IP)
{
return(pass);
}
```

Comment: I haven't checked it out, yet.